# Does Visual Studio (2010) updates IDL file automatically upon change in my code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, com, atl

When I make a change in my ATL class (e.g. adding new interface or implementing a new method), do I need to update the IDL file or the Visual Studio (2010) does it automatically (when not using wizards) ?

[Sorry.. somewhat NOOBie question..]

EDIT: Rephrasing: the only way to evade updating the IDL file manually every time is using the Visual Studio wizards ?

Comment: Yes, that's the point of the wizard.  It makes sure that the .idl, .h, .cpp and .rgs files stay in sync.  Getting them out of sync can produce very hard to diagnose runtime failure.  Why you want to 'evade' updating the .idl is very unclear and sounds unwise.

Comment: I meant evade updating the .idl *manually*. So I guess the wizards is the way to go.. The whole thing started when I wanted to implement the IPersistFile interface, but in the "Implement Interface Wizard" I don't know what "type library" to choose. How do I know in which library a certain interface exists ?

Comment: No, the wizard is not the way to go. Apparently there's no need to update the IDL.